# ESXi Hardware Monitoring

Tags: vmware-esxi, hp, hp-proliant

I have one single ESXi host on a Proliant ML350 G6. I'm using the free ESXi version and we don't have a license for vCenter.

What I would like to know is how I can get alerts when one of the hardware components fail. Is there a way to do that in iLO or is there an external tool that can monitor the ESXi host and send me email alerts when a hardware component fails?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Pay for the vSphere Essentials package for $500-$600US. That will give you a proper vCenter, configurable with email alerts, for up to *three* host servers.

Short of that, you're limited to ensuring you have the ESXi CIM agents installed (or are using an HP-specific ESXi build). The hardware and storage health alerts will appear in your vSphere console.

See: [Monitoring Dell/HP Servers Running ESXi (Free)](https://serverfault.com/questions/378966/monitoring-dell-hp-servers-running-esxi-free/378970#378970)

You can also view hardware status for all of those components using your ILO interface. An external monitoring package (HP SIM) is also helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Try this [Nagios plugin](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Hardware/Server-Hardware/HP-%28Compaq%29/check_ilo2_health/details). It offers monitoring of the systems fans, temperature and other system parts you may need.

It does not need installation of any sw within the OS. It connects to the Ilo and gets the important information by connecting to the scripting interface. It is for Proliant servers ILOs with version 2 possibly, but you may try if it works for your server.

But as mentioned above, I would recommend to buy a license for vCenter. It is not that expensive and saves time otherwise spent on configuring this kind of 'hacks'.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this http://www.veeam.com/virtual-server-management-one-free.html?ad=menu This is free version and its quite interesting. It can send alerts via email. There are 2 apps veeam monitor and veeam reporter. I found it today and didnt install reporter yet. But monitor is quite useful