# ESXi 5.x unable to start sfcbd for hardware monitoring

Tags: vmware-esxi, hp, hp-proliant, ilo

I've been trying to configure my ESXi server to take advantage of hardware monitoring via iLO drivers.  However, no matter what I do to try and start the sfcbd service, I get a list of menu options.

I'm running `/etc/init.d/sfcbd-watchdog start` and this returns a list of command-line switches to add to the command (none of which work).

It makes me think something is corrupted within sfcbd.  My end goal is to simply have hardware monitoring through ESXi.  Please note that I have already installed the HP ESXi AMS Offline bundle and restarted the server.

Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: I'm confused. Which HP ProLiant server model and generation is this? Please include that information, the version of the ESXi involved and whether you've installed the entire HP offline bundle.

Comment: @ewwhite it's a DL380 g7 and running ESXi 5.0 and I've installed the HP offline bundle here: http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=4091432&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState%3Didx%253D%257CswItem%253DMTX_77730c01570b47e9a20c330d24%257CswEnvOID%253D4115%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken

Comment: HP Agentless Monitoring is not compatible with your server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what the `sfcbd-watchdog` service has to do with any of this.

If you wish to monitor a ***Gen8 ProLiant*** server through the ILO-only, you only need the **[HP AMS Offline bundle](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=5177958&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=idx%253D2%257CswItem%253DMTX_54613e45829241d5aeadf1157d%257CswEnvOID%253D4141%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D4%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken)** to be installed on the host.

**Edit - You're using a G7 ProLiant. Agentless Management is only supported on ILO4 and Gen8 systems.**

If you're interested in general HP and VMware monitoring, check the following:

[How do you monitor your HP hardware while running virtual servers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/451190/how-do-you-monitor-your-hp-hardware-while-running-virtual-servers/451231#451231)

[Monitoring Dell/HP Servers Running ESXi (Free)](https://serverfault.com/questions/378966/monitoring-dell-hp-servers-running-esxi-free/378970#378970)

Comment: Where did you find that AMS is only support on Gen8 systems?

Comment: @inquisitor HP AMS is just not available for G7 and ILO3 systems. I'm sorry.

Comment: I ask because I downloaded this bundle directly from HP under `Software Management` for a DL380 G7.  The notes only seem to indicate that that there is support for G8.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I just read a user guide for AMS and you're correct.  HP should not include this as an available download for servers that do not have iLO4 and are g8!

Comment: Here's the [software and driver listing for your server and VMware ESXi 5.x](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdHome/?sp4ts.oid=4091432&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState%3DswEnvOID%253D4141%257CswLang%253D%257Caction%253DlistDriver&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken). There is no AMS package available for that model.

Comment: If you have vSphere, monitor your hosts that way. If you have a single standalone host, you have fewer options, but can see health in the vSphere client.

Comment: I have vSphere but the hardware status tab is not enabled; which I believe is all related to AMS not being compatible with my model.

Comment: It has nothing to do with AMS. Please see the links I posted in my answer. You will need to download and install the *HP ESXi Utilities Offline Bundle* and the *HP ESXi Offline Bundle for VMware*. In your vCenter, go to `Plug-ins -> Manage Plug-ins` and make sure vCenter Hardware Status is Enabled.

Comment: I went to `Administration -> Solutions -> Plug-In Management` and that's the only place I can find to manage plug-ins... and this does not make mention of a vCenter Hardware Status.

Comment: Also... the sfbdc-watchdog service starts up the cim service in esxi.

Answer (score 1):

There's something in the `start` function of the `/etc/init.d/sfcbd-watchdog` script that has a syntax problem, and that is what is giving you the "usage output" (list of command line switches).

Comment: It's actually not a `usage output` return, it's like this: `ps: no non-option arguments` and then and list of command line args for the `ps` command.