# datastore and network performance issues in ESXI

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere, datastore

I am having a serious problem with a server running ESXi 6.0
Everything worked great last week. Now out of no where the whole thing is basically useless. I am getting datastore latency of up to 51 seconds! Nothing has changed between now and last week other than installing some software on a VM.

[Datastore Lag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZ4Br.jpg)

The server is an HP Proliant DL360 G7
2X hexacore Xeon X5650  2.67GHz
144 GB RAM.
8x 300GB HP 10k SAS hard drives in RAID 10.

I have 6 VM's on the machine, most with thin provisioned VMDK's
Out of 1.6 TB I have 600GB free.

2 of the VM's seem to run fine, the others run like total crap.

I have tried rebooting the server. Assigning more resources to the slow VM's (even tho they have plenty) and nothing is working.

Even with every VM powered off I have tried to move the VM's off the server to a storage device on the network and I am getting spikes in data transfer. It will move at 20 -30MB /s for about 20 seconds then drop down to near 0 for a few minutes then back up in a constant pattern which suggests a bottleneck somewhere.

When I try to move data between virtual drives in a powered on VM, same thing happens. Right now I am trying to transfer a file and it is going about 200kb/s.  On the slow VM's it takes over 20 minutes to boot and is so slow you can't use it.

[Disk transfer rate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KKSg.jpg)

I am at a total loss. Any help in resolving this would me much appreciated.

Comment: Is this a standalone host or part of a cluster managed by vCenter? Can you post the version and build number of your ESXi host? Was this installed with the HP-specific version of ESXi?

Comment: IT is a standalone host. It was not installed with the HP version of ESXi. 

It is ESXi 6.0.0  3620759

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that your issue is related to the [health of your RAID controller's cache and battery/flash module](https://serverfault.com/questions/450242/what-is-the-memory-module-on-a-raid-card-needed-for/450253#450253). If the RAID write cache has been disabled due to failure of the RAID battery, for instance, your write performance on the array will degrade severely.

There are a couple of ways to check this. Can you specify if this is a standalone host or part of a cluster managed by vCenter?

---

**Edit:**

*This host does not appear to have the HP-specific version of ESXi installed.*

Without this [or the HP add-ons for ESXi](https://serverfault.com/questions/378966/monitoring-dell-hp-servers-running-esxi-free/378970#378970), there's no monitoring of the host hardware or any of the utilities necessary to check system status.

Normally, you can see status graphically like this:

[image]

[image]

I suspect you have a storage battery failure, considering the G7 line was introduced in 2011 and the batteries tend to last 3-5 years in production. If this was a used server, this is the likely cause. You should add them from [here](http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=4091432&swItemId=MTX_319543df03214c1aa75130e3d3&swEnvOid=4183), [here](http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=4091432&swItemId=MTX_2ab3cf5ff7d444a2a574c8436c&swEnvOid=4183) and [here](http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=4091432&swItemId=MTX_1c77105877a24ece849f3d547f&swEnvOid=4183).

At the command line, running the following will show your battery's status ([other handy commands](https://kallesplayground.wordpress.com/useful-stuff/hp-smart-array-cli-commands-under-esxi/)):

```
/opt/hp/hpssacli/bin/hpssacli ctrl all show config detail | grep -i battery
```

Output:

```
[root@c2-esx1:~] /opt/hp/hpssacli/bin/hpssacli ctrl all show config detail | grep -i battery
   No-Battery Write Cache: Disabled
   Battery/Capacitor Count: 1
   Battery/Capacitor Status: OK
```

If the part is bad, we can force it to ignore the battery status using the following *(there's risk if you don't have stable power for your equipment)*:

```
/opt/hp/hpssacli/bin/hpssacli ctrl slot=0 modify nbwc=enable
```

This will at least restore performance while you arrange for parts repair/replacement.

Comment: This is a standalone host. It is not managed by vcenter server. Its just ESXi on a server and I connect to it with the Vsphere client. (not the web client)

Comment: Please add the build number and let us know if you installed the HP-specific version of ESXi.

Comment: It is not the HP specific version. It is ESXi 6.0.0  3620759

Comment: @KyleVaughan The HP version definitely needs to be installed for actual monitoring and to have tools to work on the server. But you probably have a RAID battery failure.

Comment: I tried to install the HP version but it wouldn't boot so I went with the standard version.  I am currently in the process of installing the HP array controller drivers and the utilities ( rebooting now ) will report back with my findings. Hopefully the server boots up as I have no physical access to it. (it's on the other side of the country )

Comment: According to the CLI, the battery is good. Any other ideas?

Comment: Please http://pastebin.com the output of `/opt/hp/hpssacli/bin/hpssacli ctrl all show config detail`

Comment: When I run   ctrl slot=3 modify dwc=enable forced
It says that the operation is not supported with the current configuration and gives Reason = cache disabled. 

Any ideas?

Comment: That's not something you should enable. What is the full status output?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/iP9N1EXp

Comment: @KyleVaughan - See **_"Cache Status Details: A cache error was detected. Run a diagnostic report for more information."_** - The ECC RAM on the controller detected this error. The module may have a problem. Try reseating it.

Comment: Hmm well that's going to be impossible. The server is about 5,000 Km away.

Comment: Well, that's what's wrong.

Comment: IS there any way to disable the controller cache and use the drive cache?

Comment: They're not the same thing... This is up to you to handle, though. A reseat or hard power-off/on may help.

Comment: How did you determine "The ECC RAM on the controller detected this error. The module may have a problem. " ?

Comment: The error is in your pastebin output.

Comment: So would this cause inconsistent behavior? For instance right now I am copying files within a VM and everything seems just fine. It's seeding away at 80 mb/s and there is no datastore latency. Yet 30 minutes ago i was getting 480 kb/s with 57 second latency.

Comment: You clearly have an error and a hardware problem. The server is no longer healthy. Repairing this will restore your performance.

Comment: Thank you all. I had someone on site re-seat the cache board and now the cache reads as OK.  My datastore latency has gone from 51 seconds down to 6 seconds peak max.  Network throughput is now 80+ MB/s .

I am curious though why re-seating the card would help. You would think if it was making enough connection to read that it is there then it would just work.

Comment: It probably vibrated loose or was not securely installed.